# push data into gstreamer rtsp server

Tags: c, gstreamer

i'm new to gstreamer / rtsp so, sorry if it's a basic mistake.

Im trying to set up a pipeline that end with a appsink that push data into a rtsp server starting with an appsrc.

It would be:
videotestsrc -> x264enc -> appsink (push data to src as soon as received)
and
appsrc -> rtph264pay

I tried the example here : https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-appsrc.c but it uses "need-data" and I would really prefer to push data from the sink directly.

I get this warning on the first push to appsrc when running my code: `GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:20:43.792: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed` which is probably the reason why I cant read the stream from gst-launch or ffplay. But I dont understand it
The following calls do not trigger the warning

The code is in a c++ class, but its mostly using gstreamer

```cpp
std::set<GstRTSPMedia *> mRTSPStreams;
GMainLoop *mMainLoop = nullptr;
std::mutex mMediaMutex;

GStreamer_RTSP::GStreamer_RTSP()
{
    gst_init( NULL, NULL );
    mMainLoop = g_main_loop_new( NULL, FALSE );
    InitPipeline();
    InitRTSP();
}
void GStreamer_RTSP::InitPipeline()
{
    GstElement *lPipeline = gst_pipeline_new( "x264-pipeline" );

    GstElement *lSource  = gst_element_factory_make( "videotestsrc", "source" );
    GstElement *lEncoder = gst_element_factory_make( "x264enc", "x264-encoder" );
    GstElement *lSink    = gst_element_factory_make( "appsink", "appsink" );

    gst_bin_add_many( GST_BIN( lPipeline ), lSource, lEncoder, lSink, NULL );

    g_object_set( lEncoder, "tune", 4  , NULL ); // 4 = zerolatency 

    GstCaps *lCaps = gst_caps_from_string( "video/x-raw,width=1000,height=500,framerate=10/1" );
    if( !gst_element_link_filtered( lSource, lEncoder, lCaps ) )
    {
        gst_caps_unref( lCaps );
        throw std::runtime_error( "Cannot link caps." );
    }
    gst_caps_unref( lCaps );

    gst_element_link( lEncoder, lSink );

    // Make sink emit signals (new-preroll and new-sample) on each new frame
    // sync = false => display frame as soon as it arrives (ignore timestamps)
    g_object_set( G_OBJECT( lSink ), "emit-signals", TRUE, "sync", FALSE, NULL );
    g_signal_connect( lSink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK( &GStreamer_RTSP::NewFrameFromSink ), this );

    //  Start playing
    GstStateChangeReturn ret = gst_element_set_state( lPipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING );
    if( ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error( "Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state." );
    }
}

void GStreamer_RTSP::InitRTSP()
{
    // create a server instance
    GstRTSPServer *lServer = gst_rtsp_server_new();
    gst_rtsp_server_set_service( lServer, "8554" );

    // get the mount points for this server, every server has a default object that be used to map uri mount points to media factories
    GstRTSPMountPoints *lMounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points( lServer );

    // make a media factory for a test stream. The default media factory can use gst-launch syntax to create pipelines.
    // any launch line works as long as it contains elements named pay%d. Each element with pay%d names will be a stream
    GstRTSPMediaFactory *lFactory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new();
    gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch( lFactory, "( appsrc name=rtspsrc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )" );

    gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared( lFactory, TRUE );

    /* attach the test factory to the /test url */
    gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory( lMounts, "/test", lFactory );

    /* don't need the ref to the mapper anymore */
    g_object_unref( lMounts );

    // attach the server to the default maincontext
    if( gst_rtsp_server_attach( lServer, NULL ) == 0 )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error( "Unable to start rtsp server" );
    }

    /* add a timeout for the session cleanup */
    // g_timeout_add_seconds( 2, (GSourceFunc)timeout, lServer );

    // notify when our media is ready, This is called whenever someone asks for the media and a new pipeline with our appsrc is created
    g_signal_connect( lFactory, "media-configure", (GCallback)&GStreamer_RTSP::MediaConfigure, this );

    /* start serving, this never stops */
    g_print( "stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test\n" );

    g_main_loop_run( mMainLoop );

    return;
}

GstFlowReturn GStreamer_RTSP::NewFrameFromSink( GstElement *aElement, void *aParent )
{
    GStreamer_RTSP *lThis = (GStreamer_RTSP *)aParent;
    if( lThis->mRTSPStreams.empty() )
    {
        // Nobody connected to stream
        return GST_FLOW_OK;
    }

    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( lThis->mMediaMutex );
    GstSample *aSample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample( GST_APP_SINK( aElement ) );
    // GstBuffer *lBuffer = gst_sample_get_buffer( aSample );

    for( const auto &lOutgoingStream : lThis->mRTSPStreams )
    {
        GstElement *lElement    = gst_rtsp_media_get_element( lOutgoingStream );
        GstElement *lRTSPSource = gst_bin_get_by_name( GST_BIN( lElement ), "rtspsrc" );
        gst_app_src_push_sample( GST_APP_SRC( lRTSPSource ), aSample );

        // GstBuffer *app_buffer = gst_buffer_copy_deep( lBuffer );
        // gst_app_src_push_buffer( GST_APP_SRC( lRTSPSource ), app_buffer );

        gst_object_unref( lElement );
        gst_object_unref( lRTSPSource );
    }

    gst_sample_unref( aSample );
    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

void GStreamer_RTSP::MediaConfigure( GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory, GstRTSPMedia *media, void *aParent )
{
    GStreamer_RTSP *lThis = (GStreamer_RTSP *)aParent;

    GstElement *lElement    = gst_rtsp_media_get_element( media );
    GstElement *lRTSPSource = gst_bin_get_by_name( GST_BIN( lElement ), "rtspsrc" );
    gst_app_src_set_stream_type( GST_APP_SRC( lRTSPSource ), GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM );
    auto caps = gst_caps_new_simple( "video/x-h264", "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1000, "height", G_TYPE_INT, 500, "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 10, 1, NULL );
    gst_app_src_set_caps( GST_APP_SRC( lRTSPSource ), caps );
    gst_caps_unref( caps );

    gst_object_unref( lElement );
    gst_object_unref( lRTSPSource );

    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( lThis->mMediaMutex );
    lThis->mRTSPStreams.insert( media );
    g_signal_connect( media, "unprepared", (GCallback)&GStreamer_RTSP::MediaUnconfigure, aParent );
}

void GStreamer_RTSP::MediaUnconfigure( GstRTSPMedia *media, void *aParent )
{
    GStreamer_RTSP *lThis = (GStreamer_RTSP *)aParent;
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( lThis->mMediaMutex );
    lThis->mRTSPStreams.erase( media );
}
```

Am i missing something in the logic? And what does this error mean?

ffplay is just stuck when I try to run it: `ffplay rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test` -> `nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0`

I don't think it matters, but i'm on wsl2 and trying to play it from either wsl or the host

Thanks

Comment: Try setting the appsrc format property to GST_FORMAT_TIME.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch it fixes the error indeed. But I still receive nothing from ffplay. And if I try to copy the buffer instead of the sample, I get an error 503